# How to SUM up 2 Columns into 1 Column SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sum

I am really new to SQL Server so I wanted to know a few things. I made a database and was trying to make it so the 3rd column sums up the 1st and 2nd. I'm not sure if I have to query into CREATE TO or INSERT TO. Since I am new, I don't really know what to search for online.

For Example:

CREATE TO QUERY displays:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[INVOICE](
    [ID_Order] [nchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [Product_Total] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [Shipping_Total] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [Total_Price] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [MCT_Code] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [ID_Shipping] [nchar](10) NULL,
```

While INSERT TO QUERY displays:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[INVOICE]
           ([ID_Order]
           ,[Product_Total]
           ,[Shipping_Total]
           ,[Total_Price]
           ,[MCT_Code]
           ,[ID_Shipping])
     VALUES
       (<ID_Order, nchar(10),>
       ,<Product_Total, decimal(18,2),>
       ,<Shipping_Total, decimal(18,2),>
       ,<Total_Price, decimal(18,2),>
       ,<MCT_Code, nchar(10),>
       ,<ID_Shipping, nchar(10),>)
GO
```

Basically I want `[Product_Total] + [Shipping_Total]` to autopopulate the sum into `[Total_Price]`. If it's done through the query, do I press execute? I have tried a few things but there always seems to be an error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for a computed column:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188300.aspx

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I didn't even know what to google or the name of this, thank you!